# Automatically open document when only one document is listed in repeat control

Tags: xpages

I have a repeat control for a domino view which displays the results from a search field.

As you type more characters into the search field the number of items in the list is reduced. If/When the the list only contains a single item I would like to open item automatically, without having to click the link.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Edit: after some very interesting responses, here are some screenshots

I have 3 elements on the page, a searchbar, a repeat control and a form:

[image]

When I start typing in the search bar, the repeat is refreshed with every keystroke:

[image]

the list is reduced, typing the next character ...

[image]

again the list is reduced, only 2 left, typing again....

[image]

Only one left, now it would be time to open the document in the form ..... without clicking the link.

I've tried several events on the page, but it seems that I could not find the one that will allow me to "select" the document and display the data in the form.

It seems that it's not as simple as I thought

Comment: That would actually make a nice custom control: the redirecting repeat - seems like a pattern that can be reused in many places

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to open the link automatically I don't know if I would try to base it on the getRowCount() of the repeat itself.  You don't want to even get that far right?  you just want  to go to the single document.
I would put a function in beforePageLoad event maybe.  Not totally sure which event but I'd try that first.  Use SSJS and do a lookup that would basically return a collection of what the repeat would show.  If the collection count = 1 then get your destination from that entry and do your redirection from there.

That what I would try at least.  Interesting scenario!

Comment: Hi David, nice to read you here, after many hours of reading (and hearing) your stuff for Xpages. Well its not soo simple. I've combined a lot of yours (and others) tips in my application.

Comment: Could you please post some code so we can base our answers on that? Where do you get your data from (datasource of the repeat ) etc.

Comment: Here are more details. The page have several elements: a Repeat (based on a domino view), a form with the document details. The repeat includes a link to open the document in the form. The Repeat-view is filtered by searchbar, wich updates on every keystroke. Typing a search value in the searchbar reduces the amount of columns in the repeat and I want to show the document detail as soon as there is only one row left in the repeat control. So I need a kind of eventhandler that is fired up on every refresh of the panel, checks the count of the repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I see the screenshots this might be easier then you think and I have already implemented something similar on an internal application that I have built. It does rely on the fact that each entry in the list is 100% unique.

First of all you will need to bind the search field to a scoped variable and the onchange/onkeypress event will need to perform a partial refresh of a panel that contains both the list and the document portion of the page.

For the list the link on each item should set the value of the same scoped variable used in the search box and clicking the link should be set to run a partial refresh of the document area.

For the document area you will need two panels, the first panel will only display if there is no matching document and the second panel will only display if there is a matching document, you can do this in the rendered section by writing some ssjs that grabs a handle to the db/view and does a dblookup and returns either true or false if the document exists depending on panel your dealing with.

With this setup, when somebody clicks a link or fills out the searchbox the scoped variable will contain a value, the document panels will then check to see if this is a unique value in the view in the db and update themselves to either display the 'no document' panel or the 'document' panel accordingly.

Comment: Hi Declan, maybe a misunderstanding. Nearly everything you described is already done, the only "problem" I have, is that, if the repeat only contains excatly ONE row, I would like to show the data of the remaining entry in the form panel. The rows shown in the repeat control are based on fulltext-search, not just on the column/key values, so how could I do a DbLookup, with exactly the same results ? Thx Thomas

Comment: ahh, you never said it was a full-text search. Let me think about that for and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a evaluation script to the entry of your repeat control which checks the size of your repeat control using the method getRowCount() from the component. If this is 1 you could execute a context.redirectToPage("yourpage.xsp?id=yourid",true) this forces the current page to send a redirect request back to the browser and therefore redirects you to the correct page.

All you need to know is which xpage you need to open and which parameters you should use. But these could be retrieved from the content you are iterating over.

Comment: But how (and where in the repeat control ) do I add the evaluation script? Could you offer a small sample. Thx Thomas